# How to configure Ubuntu for persistent X session convenient to use both locally and via remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

Sorry to repeat an old question, but I think this topic would deserve a fresh answer for recent versions of Ubuntu with remote desktop feature.

I've enabled both remote desktop and xrdp, both work but reserve the same rdp-port. Remote desktop is limited to logged in and unlocked session, so it is not safe to use for yourself - but more like intended for ability for remote support. To occassionally use it however, I find myself restarting gdm3 service in order to kick out existing xrdp sessions and vice-versa if remote desktop has the port reserved I have to kick my local session away to use xrdp again.

I would like to be able to login to persistent session both locally and remotely. What guide should I follow in Ubuntu 22.04 to do this ?